# Does API 23 features could run in API 25? android studio

Tags: codeigniter

I am having a problem when i moved from sdk 23.0.1 to 25.1.0 
i upgraded my sdk version because i run a program that needs to upgrade sdk version but suddenly my 23.0.1 version xml does not rendering

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVtGq.png)

Comment: You need to follow the instructions and update Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Update your android studio or go from 23.0.1 to 25.1.0 for all your file.

Comment: So i just need to update android studio and i wont be able to have a problem anymore when it comes on dependencies?

my problem is my old 23.0.1 has a program and when i installed 25.0.1 because i need it my old 23.0.1 has an error and the XML files arent working anymore.